# How to link animation of object A to object B while keeping A's original location?

Tags: animation, linked-data

When I link animation data of a cube to a sphere and animate, cube snaps to the sphere's location and take the same path while moving! How to link while keeping cube's original location?

Answer (score 2):

One way to recycle motion without having the objects overlap is to use NLAs.  This is not exactly trivial.  You have to

- place the action inside an action strip
- put a location keyframe on the second object
- change the action strip blending mode from Replace to Add

Another strategy would be to make the second object a child of an Empty or other object.  You can adjust the location of the parent to set the origin of the modified coordinate system.

In the following screenshot you can see the lower left window is the NLA editor illustrating that Cube.001 has one NlaTrack with the shared action, and its primary action is the offset keyframe.  The action strip has its Blending set to Add.

In the upper right outliner window you can see Cube.002 is parented to an Empty.

[image: various techniques for sharing motion but altering location]

Answer (score 1):

Once you link the two objects, click on the cube and move to where you want or its original location. Then use the sphere to control both of their locations together.
hope this was helpful!
-Noah